# Problem involving the incentres of the triangle formed by drawing the altitude of the triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let ABC be a triangle and D be the foot of perpendicular from A onto BC. Let E and F be incentres of triangles ABD and ADC respectively. The line EF when extended both sides meet AB in K and AC in L. Show that AK = AL if and only if AB = AC or angle A = 90.

I proved that AK = AL when AB = AC. However I am unable to prove it when angle A = 90, also can anyone help me with the proof of the converse. I am unable to conclude anything by angle chasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It is practical to assume that $D\equiv O$ and set $BD=x_L, DC=x_R$ and $DA=y$. We have:

$$ E = \frac{x_L A + y B}{x_L+y+\sqrt{x_L^2+y^2}},\qquad F  = \frac{x_R A + y C}{x_R+y+\sqrt{x_R^2+y^2}}.$$
The constraint $AK=AL$ is equivalent to the orthogonality between the $EF$-line and the angle bisector of $\widehat{BAC}$. Let $N$ be the foot of such angle bisector: by the angle bisector theorem
$$ N=\frac{B\sqrt{x_L^2+y^2} + C\sqrt{x_R^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x_L^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x_R^2+y^2}}$$
and $EF\perp AN$ is equivalent to
$$ AE^2-AF^2 = NE^2 - NF^2. $$
I leave to you to compute what this constraint gives in terms of $y,x_L,x_R$, namely $x_L=x_R$ or $x_L x_R = y^2$.

Comment: Is the L in the question same as the foot of perpendicular you defined. I guess not right, also how did you get that expression for L?

Comment: @saisanjeev: I shouldn't have used the letter $L$, now fixed. By the angle bisector theorem, $\frac{BN}{NC}=\frac{BA}{AC}$, hence it is straightforward to write $N$ in terms of a convex combination of $B$ and $C$.